# Print to textbox from sqlite database from bottom up in Python

Tags: python, sqlite, csv, tuples

The code below will loop through the cursor and print to the textbox. It pushes the next line down and prints the next one above it. I am unsure how to reverse it or place it on the next line instead of above in the textbox.

```
 def favorite_store(self):
    self.text.delete("1.0", "end")
    cursor = con.execute("""SELECT lastName, firstName
 FROM person JOIN stores ON (favoriteStore = stores.storeID)
 where storeName = 'Total Wine'""")
    for row in cursor:
        self.text.insert(0.0, (row[0], row[1]), )
        self.text.insert(0.0,"\n")
```

This is the output of the code:

```
Casey Mick
Cohen Jessica
Washington Martha
```

When it should print as:

```
Washington Martha
Cohen Jessica
Casey Mick
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def favorite_store(self):
    self.text.delete("1.0", "end")
    cursor = con.execute("""SELECT lastName, firstName
 FROM person JOIN stores ON (favoriteStore = stores.storeID)
 where storeName = 'Total Wine' ORDER BY lastName DESC, firstName DESC""")
    for row in cursor:
        self.text.insert(0.0, (row[0], row[1]), )
        self.text.insert(0.0,"\n")
```

Comment: I know that changing the sql statement with give the desired results but I am trying to modify the code.

Comment: I did'nt work with the Tkinter, but in the [documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm) written:
`line/column indexes are the basic index type. They are given as strings consisting of a line number and column number, separated by a period. Line numbers start at 1, while column numbers start at 0, like Python sequence indexes.`
self.text.insert(1.0, (row[0], row[1], "\n")) for inserting at the beginning.
self.text.insert(Tkinter.INSERT, (row[0], row[1], "\n")) at the end.